# Will a bluetooth 4 dongle improve connectivity with a bluetooth 2 device

Tags: bluetooth

If a computers Bluetooth dongle is upgraded to Bluetooth 4.1, will older devices on bluetooth 2, 3 etc.. see increased range or reliability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a computers Bluetooth dongle is upgraded to Bluetooth 4.1, will older devices on bluetooth 2, 3 etc.. see increased range or reliability?

No, they won't. Communications will always fall back to the best common protocol accepted by both sides.